# Negative result in MySQL query with BIGINT values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making the following query with MySQL:

```
SELECT id, from_unixtime(`timestamp`/1000, '%Y-%m-%d') as day_time, timestamp, end_timestamp, min((`end_timestamp`-`timestamp`)/60000) as min_diff_minutes from table1 WHERE imp<=130;
```

The table is the following (this table is only a small portion of the original one):

```
+--------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
|      id      |    day     |   timestamp   | end_timestamp |
+--------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 71fce85098b9 | 2014-03-09 | 1394367994962 | 1394368030106 |
| 81fgr85093y6 | 2014-03-09 | 1394367950493 | 1394367993432 |
| 12rtw63423d1 | 2014-02-15 | 1394367302837 | 1394367783463 |
| 77grs82544e7 | 2014-01-21 | 1394367003472 | 1394367903843 |
+--------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The result of the query is the following:

```
+--------------+------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+
|      id      |    day     |   timestamp   | end_timestamp | min_diff_minutes |
+--------------+------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+
| 71fce85098b9 | 2014-03-09 | 1394367994962 | 1394368030106 | -23359195.5028   |
+--------------+------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+
```

How is possible to have

> -23359195.5028

as result of the **MIN()** function, since the value "*min_diff_minutes* " is just the difference of "*end_timestamp*" with "*timestamp*" divided for 60000 ?

PS Anyway, the values "*timestamp*" and "*end_timestamp*" are of type **BIGINT**.

Comment: because you're using `double_end_timestamp` in that min() function, not `end_timestamp`. Since you haven't shown that field or its value, we can't really help you, but most likely it's much smaller than `end_timestamp`. You're also not showing the the real results, because you have a `diff` alias in the query which isn't in your output results.

Comment: Sorry about that, i have just made a mistake writing the query here ... i've just edited the post ... now i think you can help me

Comment: you are using `min()` without a `group by` clause, so probably some other record not shown has a `0` in `timestamp`, because `-23359195.5028 * 60000 = 1401551730168`. And since that'd presumably be the SMALLSET value you get from your subtraction/division, `min()` is properly returning it.

Comment: I've just checked, and there are no record in where timestamp is equal to 0

Comment: then the other possibility is that your ts/end_ts values are massively out of whack, and their difference does end up producing -23359195. `select * from yourtable where (end_timestamp - timestamp) < 0` would find any such records.

Comment: I found out that there are some field with a really low value.